# If I have pulsed dc current going though an electromagnet, with the magnetic field mimic the current at higher pulsed dc frequencies?

Tags: current, dc, pulse, high-frequency, magnet

If I have pulsed dc current going though a copper wire electromagnet with no core , will the magnetic field mimic the current at higher pulsed dc frequencies?(such as ghz)

Answer (score 3):

How are you going to produce Ghz current pulses into an INDUCTOR (For such an electromagnet is)?

V=LdI/dt after all, so doing anything much to a significant inductance at Ghz rates implies a hell of a lot of voltage.

Further at GHz rates the physical length of a conductor has to be small for it to appear as a lumped element, the wavelength at 1Ghz being only ~20cm in a typical copper wire after all, and you would need to keep things down to maybe 1/10th of a wavelength to make the usual low frequency approximations still work. If you want anything other then a sine wave, you need to do the sums to see what your physical dimension limit is for the highest harmonic of interest.

Usually by the time we are looking at GHz rates, we are talking electromagnetic fields rather then electric or magnetic ones, physical size being less of an issue in the far field (Which is electromagnetic in nature).

Comment: my intention was indeed to create a repetitive sine wave oscillation... just the same magnetic pulse over and over again... so would that work?, Also how much voltage are we talking about? I only need the the magnetic field to be slightly stronger than the earth's at a distance of 9cm... I am willing to provide ALOT a power to this invention of mine, you've been helpful either way though, thamks.

Answer (score 1):

Magneto motive force (MMF) is measured in ampere turns. If the amps and the turns are known then the MMF is a given. For H field (a bit more useful to know than MMF), H = MMF/distance so if distance is known (i.e. the average distance that the magnetic field is around the loop) or distance remains constant them H remains proportional to MMF.

Try looking up the Biot Savart law to confirm this - it also tells you how to convert H to B-fields (flux density) at any given distance from a current carrying conductor.

> I have pulsed dc current

On the face of it this shouldn't matter - if you know the value of the current at all points in time then you also know the magnetic field strength (H). However, if your pulse is in fact a voltage pulse then the current will be significantly different. Also if your pulse is a current and you are not ensuring that it doesn’t get leached away by parasitic capacitance then the current that makes the magnetic field will not be cleanly represented by the current pulse shape unless your "electromagnet" is a single turn.

Comment: the pulse is current based, how do I insure that It gets leached away?

Comment: I fixed that typo.

Comment: oh... well then how do I insure that it doesn't get leached away?

Comment: thanks for informing me that the magnetic field is proportional to the current btw, I was worried the wire would get magnetized, and disrupt it's own field, preventing the appropriate on/off oscillating field generation...